# Failover stragtegy for replicant db via 3rd party

Tags: database-design, sql-server-2012, replication, failover, disaster-recovery

We use a Multi-tenant SaaS product hosted in the providers network. They provide us a 3 replicate db for our data, updated approximately every 30 min. We used this replicant database for our read heavy web application that does reporting etc.

The problem we are seeing frequently is their replication fails. Depending on which replicant database  crashes, this can cause the loss of whole tables and  our front end system.

What strategy can improve our fault tolerance from 3rd parties replication problems?